# Mosfet Gate Pull-Down and Gate Resistor Failure

Tags: inverter, gate-driving, pulldown

I'm trying to make an inverter which has a dc bus of 350V and output of 220V(spwm). The problem is I've run the circuit two times and in the first one the gate resistors explode and in the second one gate pull-downs explode. When I disconnected dc bus and checked pwm, everything is fine, I have all the true pwms. Then I disconnected pwms and applied dc bus voltage to the circuit, I also got everything true(DC bus is a rectifier output). But when I applied pwms to the dc bus I got my gate resistors and pull-down explode.

I'm using IRFPF30PBF mosfet, 100Ohm gate resistor and 1kOhm pulldown.

What can cause this resistor failures I can't understand.

Here is the schematic I'm using:[image]

Thank you.

Edit: Photo of PCB(one of two halfbridges and IR2110 driver)[image]

Comment: 1) Are you sure you wired the MOSFETs correctly?  2) Run your early testing at a reduced DC Bus voltage so things don't explode. Maybe 12V. After it works reliably at 12V, then raise to 350V.

Comment: @Mattman944 I'm about to try this, thank you, but I just wonder what can cause this resistor failures, because it's the first time I'm encountering this problem.

Comment: What is the power rating for the gate resistor and the pull down resistor? What kind of rise time are you getting from U1/U2? My guess is that with those fat MOS you are exceeding the max power in the Rs at startup, when the gates of Q1 and Q3 are at ground potential.

Comment: Are you SURE that the FET pinout is correct? | Is anything else other than resistors damaged? | Photo of PCB? - clear well lit focused - all relevant circuitry and only relevant circuitry

Comment: Lower FET resistors or upper FET or both or ...?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon PCB photo added, also the driver(IR2110) damaged, high side gate resistors and low side pulldowns damaged.

Comment: @VladimirCravero resistors are 1/4W

Comment: I am not sure of the rise times you have there, but for the high side R blowing you have a (supposedly) brief period when the full 350V is across the 10R. That is more than 12kW... Now, of course you do not need a 12kW part, but my guts tells me 1/4 is not nearly enough... We need more information on the transition times to help you out though.

Comment: I assume that this is a top side view of PCB with [**FETS**](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91249/91249.pdf) mounted on this side of board with bodies facing "down" out of picture. Yes? (That makes sense of pinouts).

Comment: PCB image and cct diagram have different component numbers. This is bearable but makes quick cross reference hard(er)